# round off currency using regular exp

Tags: javascript, regex, rounding, currency

I have multiple currency inputs i.e $1,869.96. I need to round up my currency into $1,870 as a whole number without any decimal places.

The regular expression I used is

```
"$"+ a.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
```

Can anybody help me in modifying the existing one to round up the value as a whole number without decimal places.Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean. I don't get any decimal places using your regex.

Comment: I don't get why aren't you using `Math.round()`.

Comment: Do you really have commas in your number? You'll need to remove them before you use any math operations.

Comment: You need to convert the string to float and then round it with Math.round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
    function formatVal(a){ 
    var c = '';
    if(a.toString().indexOf('$') !== -1){
        a = Math.round(Number(a.toString().replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,"")));
        if (isNaN(a)){ 
            c=a;
        }else { 
            c ="$"+a.toFixed(0).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$&,');
            if(c == '$0'){ c = "";}
        } 
    }
    return c; 
}
    
console.log(formatVal('$1,869.96'));
console.log(formatVal('$1,869'));
console.log(formatVal('sssss'));
console.log(formatVal(42));
```

Comment: `toFixed(2)` should be `toFixed(0)`

Comment: Changing from `toFixed(2)` to `toFixed(0)` seems to break comma insertion. Something like `return '$' + number.toFixed(0).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$&,');` seems to work...

Comment: Nice, this equal   `return '$' + number.toFixed(0).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$&,');  `

Comment: Hey Nerdvoso,

can you please  modify the same in my existing code and see my rounding function. It will be a great help,
Here is how my code looks like

function formatVal(a){
    a=parseInt(a);
   //return value based on numeric /non-numeric
    if (isNaN(a)){
        c=a;
    }else
    {
        c ="$"+a.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
   }
    return c;
 }

Comment: I'm getting the error as Uncaught TypeError: a.replace is not a function

Comment: @JainP try now, added conversion `toString()`

Comment: awesome.its rounding up the values.Thank you.
can you help me with one more thing, the table cell where there are no values i.e NAN those cells are displaying with $0. I want them to be blank

Comment: @JainP update, added condition `if(c == '$0'){ c = "";}`

Comment: Awesome. It's working.Thanks a lot.you made my day. Thanks.:-)

Comment: Hey Nerdvoso, there is a special case in my api output where for a particular input it gives me  error:42. But after using this round up regex it is display it has $42, which is a bad value for my table, can it at least display error:42 in such case. Before using your round up regex I used to get blank cell for such special at least. Any insights on that will be helpful

Comment: @JainP Update answer, check now.

Comment: Hey Nerdvoso, I'm not getting values for any of the inputs , my table is showing blank. Please help.

Comment: can there made be an alert if I have error 42 coming from an api display an alert or error saying error 42., rather displaying it as $42 before sending it to regular exp, I could show my project, but I can't show here publicly

Comment: in my console no error is displayed. But in my api the error is displayed as
 "error: 42"

Comment: When there is an error, the function starts `formatVal("error:42");` ?

Comment: please check your gmail

Comment: check for these sets of inputs. zipcode 94519, Employee only ,yes